How to add custom column descriptions for Materialized views
How to can we add descriptions for columns in Materialized Views in bigquery. I cannot add anything in descriptions. Is there any way to put columns descriptions for materialized views in bigquery? Please anyone assist?
Thanks.

In BigQuery  there is a limitation that you can set descriptions for materialized views, but you cannot set descriptions for individual columns in the materialized views . However, there is a feature request filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking +1 and STAR mark to receive updates on it.
